# BufferedWriter log writing uses a lot of CPU

Tags: java, logging

I am writing an application which logs something every 20 milliseconds in a file. Because the logging occurs so often, I checked the CPU usage of the program and it's fairly high. To reduce this, i'd like to buffer the data and once it reaches a certain size, then log the data to the file. In turn this reduces the number of readwrites I have to do. Is this really an optimal approach, however?

Before:

```
public void log(String log) {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt", true));
    bw.write(log);
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
}
```

After:

```
byte[] outputbArr = log.getBytes();

for (int i = 0; i < outputbArr.length; i++) {
    this.buf[this.bufSize] = outputbArr[i];
    this.bufSize++;
    if (this.bufSize == BUFLENGTH) {
        writeLog();
        this.buf = new byte[BUFLENGTH];
        this.bufSize = 0;
    }
}

private void writeLog() {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("log.txt");
    fos.write(this.buf);
    fos.close();
}
```

Is there a better approach? How can I reduce the number of writes. What is generally the go-to approach for a situation like this?

Comment: You can do away with BufferedWriter altogether. You should look into logging utilities. Popular ones include Java's own `java.util.logging` library, `log4j`, `log4j2`, or even better, `slf4j`.

Comment: use modern logging framework - see this for asynchronous logging in batches of log4j2: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html

Answer (score 0):

I would not close the logfile once opened. Opening a file for append is at least as expensive as the writing of a message itself.

Also, depending on the reliability you require, not explicitly flushing the log writer will also speed things up. The downside is that if worst comes to worst the portion of the log still in the write buffer may be lost if the program terminates abnormally. A shutdownhook can mitigate this in many, but not all cases.

I'd prefer to wrap the FileOutputStream into a BufferedOutputStream and hand that to an OutputStreamWriter. Control the buffer size of the BufferedOutputStream. In this way the already encoded output is what is buffered, which usually (UTF8, ASCII, ISO) makes the buffer twice as effective (1 byte per character instead 2 per character buffered).